# Failed to connect with PHP 7.1/PDO under windows x64

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, pdo

PHP 7.1.9 x64 under Windows 11

ODBC Driver 13 and 17 installed

**In php.ini**

extension=php_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll

extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_ts_x64.dll

**under console, running php script which contains**

```
$drv = 'sqlsrv:server=<ip_address>;database=mydb';
$x = new PDO($drv, 'myuser', 'mypwd');
```

I get :

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for
> SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for 'myuser'

And of course with **sqlcmd**, connection succeeds with myuser/mypwd !

Comment: If you have access to the SQL Server instance via SSMS then check its Error Log for occurrences of error 18456, take note of the State numbers there and compare those State numbers against [MSSQLSERVER_18456](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-18456-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16) to determine the actual cause. With the information in the question I'm guessing that the `mydb` database doesn't exist yet, or that the `myuser` login doesn't have access to it via a user mapping.